# TS keyof 2d array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a huge 2D array that contains/represents translations, that could look like this (just as an example)

```js
const translations = {
    'login': {
        'e-mail': 'E-Mail',
        'username': 'Username',
        'forgot-password': 'Forgot your password?'
    },
    'dashboard': {
        'hello {x}': 'Hello {x] how is your day?',
        'go-to-other-page': 'Go to page...'
    }
}
```

I then made an Interface with all translation categories and their strings

```js
interface AllTranslations {
    login: {} // contains all messages,
    dashboard: {} // contains all messages
}
```

and I made a function that returns the correct translation.

```
type TranslationCategory<T = keyof AllTranslations> = keyof AllTranslations[T];

const translate = <T extends keyof AllTranslations>(key: T, message: TranslationCategory<T>, params: {[key: string]: string|number} = {} ): string => {
    const m = translations[key][message] ?? message;
    // do something with the message, format / replace params
    return m as string;
}
```

So I can use it like

```js
translate('login', 'username');
translate('dashboard', 'hello {x}', {x: 'User'});
```

and my categories as well as the string will be autocompleted.
Everything works so far but for whatever reason the line

```
type TranslationCategory<T = keyof AllTranslations> = keyof AllTranslations[T];
```

has an error `TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'AllTranslations'.`
[image]

What can I do in order to prevent this error except including a `//@ts-ignore` above it. What is the correct way to use `keyof` with a 2d array correctly with the ability to autocomplete code correctly?

A [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBt0BUpxAZ3TjGAHsDkBvAKGTuQHJ1SBzUBgLitvt4YgC0AWzjB0nRgFEBAWVHiAND150GAV3zQQcIRAkMAqpqjbdDJSvoMYpKC1JgBABzj58Ad1sATfQDFb9mDIAJ6kalDILm6eUF4A-AzKyAC%20FlZergAWAEakcLESNJaqmRCYpFQAHsn6ABJlzFUAusiZpO7IwPghYREZwQlplgz2AmCkAg6lUM5wLHpcDADiFeORcxAAdNuJvMnU%209QI5PhBYLgERCQnXBjYF4TEZBQAvNx8zGwghUl8giJifTSOSAoYqdTGUwLRhGLQ6PRgvg2OwOWbRbx%20AIOHrhdbo2IJJKpJIMDL4HJ5ApcIrFBilcpVGqLeoMyiVFptDpdHF9OADcy-KyjcaTMDTWbzfQrZBrFzzbabXb0faHMDBJwoHB4R7XEAAYWIEHsUGCAB4sMg3gBrCChGBoTBay5PE4APktyBtdod921V2e%20AA2lgmgBuahHE5nB5XFBvc3ICCVSAgLzdL2ke13J06gOugAUXq4WAUyF0bg2xZjLv1huNZqwrtLLlwQnw1MDReQpygoBYTS4Pb7AB8QGohNloMkPZRpwBKQfnPuW900ujHAhBIQe85%20mtBr1NQPl-AbFpxOJliAV%20bh3gAenvyC8FXwpF0YuX7mAYplpSvN4QKWyIiEET5QBAThEEg6ytvgSQQWA4QgGWyCuN2S4gCw4aqtWkD5qSWS5PkPilnSDQVGyNRzuGu7OvhTCsOwZHIoEaIeBiNFAA) is here and autocomplete is working perfectly, I just don't know why there is the error.

Comment: You should try `type TranslationCategory<T extends keyof AllTranslations> = keyof AllTranslations[T];`
If you `extend`, it expects your generic to be one of `keyof AllTranslations`. If you assign a default value to `T` of `keyof AllTranslations`, T will be a union of `'login'` and `'dashboard'`.

Comment: dying over here... I was so sure I tried that before but it didn't work...
Can you post that as an answer, then I'll accept it. Thank you very much for your answer and explanation (I'm new to TS)

Comment: Done, thank you for the clear question and playground, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
type TranslationCategory<T = keyof AllTranslations> = keyof AllTranslations[T];
```

What happens is that `T` is defaulted to a union of `keyof AllTranslations` (`'login' | 'dashboard'`), whereas you want `T` to be one of `keyof AllTranslations`.

You should use `extend` instead of an assigning operator:

```
type TranslationCategory<T extends keyof AllTranslations> = keyof AllTranslations[T];
```